# How do you access a MongoDB database from two Openshift apps?

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I want to be able to access my MongoDB database from 2 Openshift apps-  one app is an interactive database maintenance app via the browser, the other is the principle web application which runs on mobile devices via an Openshift app. As I see it in Openshift, MongoDB gets set up within a particular app's folder space, not independent of that space.

What would be the method to accomplish this multiple app access to the database ?

It's not ideal but is my only choice to merge the functionality of both Openshift apps into one ? That's tastes like a bad plate of spaghetti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2018 update: this applies to Openshift 2. Version 3 is very different, and however the general rules of linux and scaling apply, the details got obsolete.**

Although @MartinB answer was timely and correct, it's just a link, so let me put the essentials here.

Assuming that setting up a non-shared DB is already done, you need to find it's host and port. You can `ssh` to your app (the one with the DB) or use the `rhc`:

```
rhc ssh -a appwithdb
env | grep MONGODB
```

`env` brings all the environment variables, and grep filters them to show only Mongo-related ones. You should see something like:

```
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST=xxxxx-yyyyy.apps.osecloud.com
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT=zzzzz

xxxxx is the ID of the gear that Mongo sits on
yyyyy is your domain/namespace
zzzzz is MongoDB port
```

Now, you can use these to create a connection to the DB from anywhere in your Openshift environment. Another application has to use the xxxxx-yyyyy:zzzzz URL. You can store them in custom variables to make maintenance easier.

```
$ rhc env-set \
MYOWN_DB_HOST=xxxxx-yyyyy \
MYOWN_DB_PORT=zzzzz \
MYOWN_DB_PASSWORD=****** \
MYOWN_DB_USERNAME=admin..... \
MYOWN_DB_NAME=dbname...
```

And then use the environment variables instead of the standard ones. Just remember they don't get updated automatically when the DB moves away.

Comment: This is an extremely valuable addition to the first solution, a link to the Openshift method which requires a rebuild of your non-scaled app to be a scaled app. The benefit of this solution is for those of us who have already created an Openshift app with the DB embedded in the 1st app's area. In that case if may be incredibly difficult to unreal to start over  as a scaled app. In that case this solution is the ticket.

Comment: As of now (2 months after the OP's question) this solution doesn't appear to work - because OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST reports a dotted-quad internal IP address which is NOT accessible from other apps (even in the same account/domain)

It seems impossible to access a MongoDB cartridge from other apps at this point - I raised a separate question but it might be better addressed here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356274/openshift-sharing-mongodb-between-apps-not-possible-anymore

Comment: Thanks for this, I was using `oc env pod/mongodb-1-xxxx2 --list` [per the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#list-environment-variables) and it only returned `MONGODB_USER`, `MONGODB_PASSWORD`, `MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD` and `MONGODB_DATABASE` - do you know what your method returns a more complete list?

Comment: That's the openshift version - the original OP was about openshift 2, you (and myself too) are already on 3.x, which is quite different from the command line to the overall architecture. Can you describe your problem in a separate question?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the following article from the open shift blog: https://blog.openshift.com/sharing-database-across-applications/

Comment: WOW, written only 8 days ago. PERFECT!