# (OpenShift) Sharing MongoDB between Apps not possible anymore?

Tags: mongodb, openshift

There are articles both here and over at OpenShift itself that suggest I can configure an app with a MongoDB and then set envvars within other apps to access that DB

e.g.

[How do you access a MongoDB database from two Openshift apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593616/how-do-you-access-a-mongodb-database-from-two-openshift-apps)

and

https://blog.openshift.com/sharing-database-across-applications/

Problem is that the envvars/hostname for the app DB is either "localhost" or a dotted-quad (129.xxx.xxx.xxx) which clearly won't (and actually doesn't - I tried it) work if used in a connection-string from another app (in the same OpenShift 'domain'

Is this something OpenShift have done to discourage this sort of usage? at least on the 'free' tier?? - or am I missing something/has anyone got this working atm???

p.s. using the actual connection string for the app (e.g. app-domain.rhcloud.com) doesn't work (even from an 'internally hosted' app)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the application as scalable, then add MongoDB for it to work correctly.  MongoDB will then go onto it's own gear, with it's own ip address and port number (remember to use this port number, or nothing will work).

You will never be able to access your mongodb gear from outside of openshift without using the rhc port-forward command (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-forwarding.html) because of firewall & other security issues.

However, if you use the scaled application approach, you will be able to connect to your mongodb instance from other openshift online hosted applications.

Comment: That makes a certain amount of sense - the only downside is the one part of this app I DON'T want to scale is the backend/database - multiple READERS of the database may be needed - multiple writers never will (the nature of what they do cannot be done in parallel)

I guess a better approach now is external hosting - DBaaS - something like MongoLab to hold the data - I beleive  I can engineer them into the same Amazon 'Region' and thus minimize traffic etc. etc.

Thanks!