# Still unable to connect one Openshift app to another Openshift app's MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

After following the advice presented here:

[(OpenShift) Sharing MongoDB between Apps not possible anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356274/openshift-sharing-mongodb-between-apps-not-possible-anymore)

...which in a nutshell is this -> "You need to create the application as scalable, then add MongoDB for it to work correctly. MongoDB will then go onto it's own gear, with it's own ip address and port number (remember to use this port number, or nothing will work)."

...I am still unable to successfully connect my Node.js app to the MongoDB database living on another Node.js app in Openshift.

I have tried the following permutations of a host string that have been suggested:

1. localhost
2. 128.xxx.xxx.xxx
3. [24 character hash]-myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com

...all with the same result. No connection.

Here is the code that makes the call to setup the db connection...

```
dbProvider = function(host, port, user, pass) {
    console.re.log("Attempting to create a DB instance...");
    this.db = new Db(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_EXTDB_DBNAME, new Server(host, port, { auto_reconnect: true }, {}));
    console.re.log("created the DB instance...");
    if(this.db!= null){
        console.re.log("successfully connected to remote db %s at %s:%s",this.db,host,port);
        this.db.open(function(error, db){
            if(error){
                console.re.log("error %s attempting to open the db at %s:%s",error,host,port);
            }
            else{
                db.authenticate(user, pass, function(error, result) { //db.authenticate(user, pass, function(error, result)
                    if(error){
                        console.re.log("error %s attempting to connect to remote db at %s:%s using user %s",error,host,port,user);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.re.log("successfully connected to remote db at %s:%s using user %s",host,port,user);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        console.re.log("unable to connect to remote db at %s:%s",host,port);
    }
}
```

The above code fails at the callback from the db.open() with a null error object.

Upon inspecting the *this.db* object we see the following:

```
{
    "domain": null,
    "_events": {},
    "_maxListeners": 10,
    "databaseName": "myDb",
    "serverConfig": {
        "domain": null,
        "_events": {},
        "_maxListeners": 10,
        "host": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-myApp-myDomain.rhcloud.com",
        "port": 12345,
        "options": {
            "auto_reconnect": true
        },
        "internalMaster": false,
        "connected": false,
        "poolSize": 5,
        "disableDriverBSONSizeCheck": false,
        "ssl": false,
        "_used": true,
        "_readPreference": null,
        "socketOptions": {},
        "logger": {
            "error": "[Function]",
            "log": "[Function]",
            "debug": "[Function]"
        },
        "eventHandlers": {
            "error": [],
            "parseError": [],
            "poolReady": [],
            "message": [],
            "close": [],
            "timeout": []
        },
        "_serverState": "disconnected",
        "_state": {
            "runtimeStats": {
                "queryStats": {
                    "m_n": 0,
                    "m_oldM": 0,
                    "m_oldS": 0,
                    "m_newM": 0,
                    "m_newS": 0,
                    "numDataValues": 0,
                    "mean": 0,
                    "variance": 0,
                    "standardDeviation": 0,
                    "sScore": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "recordQueryStats": false
    },
    "options": {},
    "_applicationClosed": false,
    "bsonLib": {
        "Code": "[Function]",
        "Symbol": "[Function]",
        "BSON": "[Function]",
        "DBRef": "[Function]",
        "Binary": "[Function]",
        "ObjectID": "[Function]",
        "Long": "[Function]",
        "Timestamp": "[Function]",
        "Double": "[Function]",
        "MinKey": "[Function]",
        "MaxKey": "[Function]"
    },
    "bson": {},
    "bson_deserializer": "[ Circular {bsonLib} ]",
    "bson_serializer": "[ Circular {bsonLib} ]",
    "_state": "disconnected",
    "pkFactory": "[Function]",
    "forceServerObjectId": false,
    "safe": false,
    "notReplied": {},
    "isInitializing": true,
    "auths": [],
    "openCalled": false,
    "commands": [],
    "_callBackStore": {
        "domain": null,
        "_events": {},
        "_maxListeners": 10,
        "_notReplied": {}
    },
    "logger": "[ Circular {logger} ]",
    "slaveOk": false,
    "tag": 1460656848883,
    "eventHandlers": {
        "error": [],
        "parseError": [],
        "poolReady": [],
        "message": [],
        "close": []
    },
    "serializeFunctions": false,
    "raw": false,
    "recordQueryStats": false,
    "reaperEnabled": false,
    "_lastReaperTimestamp": 1460656848883,
    "retryMiliSeconds": 1000,
    "numberOfRetries": 60,
    "reaperInterval": 10000,
    "reaperTimeout": 30000
```

}

*Note: The host, port, and databaseName fields have been modified for privacy.*

This db object differs from a properly connecting db object by only two fields...

...both *db.serverConfig._serverState* and *db._state* equal 'connected' vs. 'disconnected'

Appreciate hearing from anyone that has successfully accomplished what I am trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please include sneak peak of advice in question itself not just link

Comment: @Kostia - I added a brief summary of the advice per your suggestion.