# Can two servers access a common mongoDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 2 webservers that I have created on ports 3000 and 4000.
One of the webservers created a database and has 3 collections..

> show dbs
>   local      0.000GB
>   sensor_db  0.000GB
>   use sensor_db
>   switched to db sensor_db
>   show collections
>   sensors
>   templategroups
>   templates

Can the 2nd server access this Database created ? if yes, I am not able to access the collections ..Is there any syntax to it?

## 1st server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app= express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sensor_db');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var sensorSchema = new Schema({
  value:{ type:Number, default:0},
  format:{type:String, default:"default"},
  id:{type:Number,required:true,unique:true},
  description:{type:String},
  type:{type:String},
  groupId:{type:Number},
  users:{type:Array,default:[]},
  admin:{type:String,default:'Undefined'},
  status:{type:String,default:'Undefined'},
  owner:{type:String,default:'Undefined'},
  templateId:{type:Number}

});
var Sensor = mongoose.model('Sensor',sensorSchema);

app.get('/sensorlist',function(req,res) {
  console.log("I recieved a GET /sensorlist request");
  Sensor.find(function(err,data){
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(data);
    res.json(data)
  });
});

app.post('/check/health',function(req,res){
  socket.emit('data', 'I need your health status', function ack(data) {
    console.log('data emit was acknowledged by Monitoring Server:', data);
    return res.json(data);
  });
});
```

## 2nd Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var express = require('express');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('connection received from Provisioning');

  // To get messages from Provisioning server
  socket.on('data', function(data, ack) {
    console.log('Message from provision is : ' + ': ' + data);
    ack('here is your data - 1111');
    console.log("Trying to access the Sensor_DB Database");

    Sensor.find(function(err,data){
      if(err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(data);
      //res.json(data);
    });
  });
});

server.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log('socket.io server listening on *:4000');
});
```

I get error - Sensor is not defined

Much Thanks
Jessi

I tried to dispay the collections once its connected to the DB but get this error message : Cannot read property 'hasListCollectionsCommand' of null

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sensor_db') ;
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");
//mongoose.connection.db
mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, names) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    names.forEach(function(e,i,a) {
      mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection(e.name);
      console.log("--->>", e.name);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: many clients can access mongodb database simultaneously. Two servers are just two clients for mongodb.. It should be able to access..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593616/how-do-you-access-a-mongodb-database-from-two-openshift-apps this can help you I believe

Comment: Thanks for the link but thats related to OpenShift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Different servers cannot share the same instance of the sensor object.

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sensor_db');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var sensorSchema = new Schema({
  value:{ type:Number, default:0},
  format:{type:String, default:"default"},
  id:{type:Number,required:true,unique:true},
  description:{type:String},
  type:{type:String},
  groupId:{type:Number},
  users:{type:Array,default:[]},
  admin:{type:String,default:'Undefined'},
  status:{type:String,default:'Undefined'},
  owner:{type:String,default:'Undefined'},
  templateId:{type:Number}

  });
var Sensor = mongoose.model('Sensor',sensorSchema);
```

This code declaring the schema for one server not for the second . so you have to declare the instance in the second server also.

Issue not with the mongo data base issue is the sensor instance that  is not have any declaration in second server.